# jquery multiselect widget issue with jquery ui upgrading to 1.10.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

jQuery UI upgrade from 1.8 to 1.10.3 is causing an issue for [multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) plugin:

> Error: cannot call methods on multiselect prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'widget'
>
> throw new Error( msg );"

Does anybody have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/akhyp/860/

Working fine with `jQuery UI 10.0.3` version.

Comment: I went through the link ,It's not working there .Can you check that once?

Comment: @user1999254 Which browser(version)?

Answer (score 0):

**Code while error was coming**

```
 $("select").multiselect("widget").find("input[value='CustShifts']:unchecked,input[value='attendance']:unchecked").each(function () {
                           this.click();
                       });
```

**Working code without error**

```
$("input[value='CustShifts']:unchecked,input[value='attendance']:unchecked").each(function () {
                           this.click();
                       });
```

Comment: Can you show some before and after code so that this question and answer can be more useful?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me..The answer I gave before did't work.This is what working for me now. @JamesMohler